# Assign values to a field in one datatable based on the range of values in two fields in another datatable

Tags: r, data.table

I have two datatables as following:

```
dt1 <- data.table(range_col = c(1, 7, 10, 15, 20), new_col = NA)
dt2 <- data.table(min_val = c(0, 6, 11, 16), max_val = c(5, 10, 15, 20), value_col = c(100, 200, 300, 400))
```

Now based on the value of column 'range_col' and range between values in 'min_val' & 'max_val' fields in data table 'dt2', corresponding values from 'value_col' of 'dt2' must be assigned to 'new_col' of 'dt1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findInterval`:

```r
dt1[, new_col := dt2$value_col[findInterval(range_col, dt2$min_val)]]

#    range_col value_col
# 1:         1       100
# 2:         7       200
# 3:        10       200
# 4:        15       300
# 5:        20       400
```

---

Another (safer) `data.table` option is `foverlaps`:

```r
setkey(dt2, min_val, max_val)
dt1[, range_col2 := range_col]

foverlaps(dt1, dt2, by.x = c("range_col", "range_col2"))[, c("range_col", "value_col")]
```

---

And in `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
inner_join(dt1, dt2, by = join_by(between(range_col, min_val, max_val))) %>% 
  select(range_col, value_col)
```

Comment: All answers related to data tables seem to be workarounds rather than direct solutions. The solution in dplyr package seems straight, however, I prefer using data tables considering their performance.

Thanks for the solutions!!

Answer (score 2):

We can use an unequal join to join `value_col` to `dt1` and then rename it to `new_col`:

```r
library(data.table)

dt1[dt2,
    .(range_col, new_col = value_col),
    on = .(range_col  >= min_val , range_col <= max_val)
    ]

#>    range_col new_col
#> 1:         0     100
#> 2:         6     200
#> 3:         6     200
#> 4:        11     300
#> 5:        16     400
```

Data from OP:

```r
dt1 <- data.table(range_col = c(1, 7, 10, 15, 20), new_col = NA)
dt2 <- data.table(min_val = c(0, 6, 11, 16), max_val = c(5, 10, 15, 20), value_col = c(100, 200, 300, 400))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>